# Python Viterbi algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

The code below is a Python implementation I found [here](http://phvu.net/2013/12/06/sweet-implementation-of-viterbi-in-python/) of the Viterbi algorithm used in the HMM model. The link also gives a test case.

In `__init__`, I understand that:

- `initialProb` is the probability to start at the given state,
- `transProb` is the probability to move from one state to another at any given time, but

the parameter I don't understand is **`obsProb`**. Can someone please explain it?

```
import numpy as np

'''
N: number of hidden states
'''
class Decoder(object):
def __init__(self, initialProb, transProb, obsProb):
    self.N = initialProb.shape[0]
    self.initialProb = initialProb
    self.transProb = transProb
    self.obsProb = obsProb
    assert self.initialProb.shape == (self.N, 1)
    assert self.transProb.shape == (self.N, self.N)
    assert self.obsProb.shape[0] == self.N

def Obs(self, obs):
    return self.obsProb[:, obs, None]

def Decode(self, obs):
    trellis = np.zeros((self.N, len(obs)))
    backpt = np.ones((self.N, len(obs)), 'int32') * -1

    # initialization
    trellis[:, 0] = np.squeeze(self.initialProb * self.Obs(obs[0]))

    for t in xrange(1, len(obs)):
        trellis[:, t] = (trellis[:, t-1, None].dot(self.Obs(obs[t]).T) * self.transProb).max(0)
        backpt[:, t] = (np.tile(trellis[:, t-1, None], [1, self.N]) * self.transProb).argmax(0)
    # termination
    tokens = [trellis[:, -1].argmax()]
    for i in xrange(len(obs)-1, 0, -1):
        tokens.append(backpt[tokens[-1], i])
    return tokens[::-1]
```

Comment: I wonder if it's not named well.  I expect that it is referring to the observation sequence.  (I don't have any experience with the vetirbi algorithm, but there is [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) )

Comment: Also, the [test](https://github.com/phvu/misc/blob/master/viterbi/test1.py) shows you that it is a numpy array.

Comment: obsProb in https://github.com/phvu/misc/blob/master/viterbi/viterbi.py corresponds to emission_probability (emit_p) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm#Example and represents the hidden state probabilities. obsProb is indexed with the input data in viterbi.py at lines 16-17 (https://github.com/phvu/misc/blob/master/viterbi/viterbi.py#L16) to initialize the trellis array at line 24 (https://github.com/phvu/misc/blob/master/viterbi/viterbi.py#L24)

Comment: @Tris Nefzger , thanks for the emit part that was confusing me .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [HMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) with `N` hidden states and `M` possible discrete observation values is defined by the following parameters:

- `initialProb` (vector of size `N`): The initial state distribution. The entry `initialProb[i]` is the probability `P(x_0 = i)` of being in state `i` initially (at time 0).
- `transProb` (matrix of size `N`x`N`): The transition probability matrix. The entry `transProb[i][j]` is the probability `P(x_{t+1} = j | x_t = i)` of transitioning from state `i` to `j`.
- `obsProb` (matrix of size `N`x`M`): The emission probability matrix. The entry `obsProb[i][j]` is the probability `P(y_t = j | x_t = i)` of emitting symbol `j` from state `i`.

Often, these parameters are named `\pi`, `T` and `E`, respectively, or `\pi`, `A` and `B`.

The standard reference on HMMs is the [tutorial by Rabiner](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf), by the way.